# Unable to load controller within $routeProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is my very first AngularJs app and created it after going through many examples on the web but I am doing something wrong here. It is highly likely because files are stored in dedicated folders. The `HomeView.html` template gets loaded fine but the controller doesn't. I mean I cannot get `greetingMessage` printed in the template. All I see is `{{ greetingMessage }}` instead of "Welcome!". What am I missing?

**Error**

```
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=HomeController
```

**App Structure**

```
app
   conponents
      home
         HomeView.html
         HomeController.js
      ...
   ...
index.js
index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <h3>AngularJS</h3>
    <hr />
    <p><a href="#!">Home</a></p>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

module.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'components/home/HomeView.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
            // I tried -> controller: 'components/home/HomeController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

**HomeView.html**

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <h4>Home</h4>
    <p>{{ greetingMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

**HomeController.js**

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('HomeController', [
    '$scope',
    function(
        $scope
    ) {
        $scope.greetingMessage = 'Welcome!';
    }]);
```

Comment: Also, don't use minified files (min.js files) during development. Those are for production. Using the non-minified files during development will allow you to have much clearer and readable error messages.

Comment: @JBNizet I'll remember that in future! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is you haven't referred `homeController.js` on `index.html`, it should place right after `index.js`. This will not solve your issue. The other thing I'd like to mention is, you shouldn't be creating `myApp` module again while registering your controller with your `myApp` module. By declaring new `module` will flush out former registered component. So just use module getter like `angular.module('myApp')` and append further components to it.

```
<script src="components/home/HomeController.js">
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('HomeController', [ '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.greetingMessage = 'Welcome!';
    }
]);
```

Comment: @PankajParkar I updated the controller as per your answer however I am getting `Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'HomeController' is not registered.` I also moved all three `<script src= ...` lines in `<head>` block to see what happens but no luck.

Comment: @BentCoder you should be providing correct path there.. please check update answer. and error still persists, let me know the what error you're getting in the console?

Comment: @PankajParkar If I had 10 more controllers, that would mean 10 more `<script src="components/home/.....js">` lines. How do I solve this issue? What practise I should use?

Comment: @BentCoder best practice would be, bundled all reference files in to single file(bundle) and refer that single file on page.. otherwise you have to refer each and every file separately on the page..

Comment: Got it. I shall do some research on that and see how it it done then. Thanks

Comment: Best practice varies based on whether you're serving from HTTP 1/* or HTTP2. Worth 10 minutes research.

Answer (score 0):

You must be attach app file and next attache your controller file in your hoem page or master page.

This example helped you 
[Angular js routing](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)